# influence of fragmentation (DF bit) on rtt and ttl

Tags: linux, tcp, ping, packet

I was doing some tests with ping on linux and I am a little bit curious about how DF bit and fragmentation works. I have been sending some packages with command **-M do** and some packages with **-M dont** and I realised that even when sending packages smaller than MTU, rtt is smaller with DF bit disabled than when DF bit is enabled. Is there really some influence of fragmentation on the rtt and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DF bit has no (real) impact on either RTT or TTL.

When sending a packet, the TTL indicates how many router hops your packet should survive. On reception, it indicates how many hops the route took (provide you know or guess the start value).

The RTT is the time a packet takes to the destination and back again. When using unfragmented ICMP echo requests (`ping`) the answer time *might* provide an estimation for the RTT - however, since ICMP usually runs with low priority the `ping` time might also be significantly larger than the RTT.

With larger ping packets and especially with fragmented ping packets, the bandwidth starts to kick in. Not only does the ping measure the time between *sending the first* fragment and *receiving the last* response fragment but you also need to consider the transmission time for all fragments in both directions. With thin links this adds more than negligible delay for `ping`.

Now, setting the DF bit just prevents you from sending fragmented echo requests.